# Is there a way to use NetBeans's deploy on save within local LAN (JAVA Servlet)

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish-4

I am working on a Java servlet project using NetBeans.

I am looking for a way to use NetBeans’s “deploy on save” on another browser of my device within LAN (locally its working fine) so that I don’t have to manually reload my browser during my development.

Recently I have decided to use proxy feature of Browsersync, but the problem of the Browsersync is, it auto reloads browser early before NetBeans completes deployment on save.

I am using GlassFish(4.1) with NetBeans.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to something different in order to achieve the solution.

I am watching “glassfish/domains/domain1/config/” folder using Browsersync. Looks like after building the project, few files modified here during hot reload (so I have used watchEvents from Browsersync).

The proxy site instantly reload after NetBeans completes deployment on save.

Following is the Browsersync command.

> These directory names have to be the full path with drive letter.

```
browser-sync start --proxy "http://localhost:8080/test" --files "src/java/com/test/, glassfish/domains/domain1/config/" --watchEvents add change " src/java/com/test/, glassfish/domains/domain1/config/" --no-notify --host 192.168.X.X --port 5000
```